# VBA Loop - Only 1 Result

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this tutorial to write a VBA Loop to search for a value in a column and pulls all rows with the criteria value.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxhRSCfHaw

It is running but it takes about 5 minutes to run and in the end I only get 1 result(row) when I should be getting thousands.

```
Sub finddata()

'1.Declare Variables
'2.Find Records that match criteria and paste them into new worksheet

Dim customcode As String
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long

customcode = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A252800").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To finalrow

If Cells(i, 46) = customcode Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 102)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`

Comment: @DavidG. - Also OP should include the worksheet names before `Range()`/`Cells()` on the right side of that formula too. Basically, just make sure that happens everywhere!

Comment: Aren't you pasting to the same row over and over again?  Please step thru the code.

Comment: @Jeeped your suggestion worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try an array.

```
Sub finddate()

Dim dataRng As Range
Dim origData, newData
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim customcode As String

customcode = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 102).End(xlUp))
End With

origData = dataRng.Value
ReDim newData(1 To UBound(origData, 1), 1 To UBound(origData, 2))

j = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(origData, 1)
    If origData(i, 46) = customcode Then
        For k = 1 To UBound(origData, 2)
            newData(j, k) = origData(i, k)
        Next
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(j, 102)) = newData
End With

End Sub
```